# Are people from Wayward Pines vegans/vegetarians?

Tags: plot-explanation, wayward-pines

I would like to know why they don't use monstrous creatures (mutated humans) (abbies) as a source of food in *Wayward Pines*. They killed so many while trying to climb the electric fence.

Comment: Because monsters' flesh isn't a primary choice for most people when it comes to food?

Comment: if they do eat monster's flesh, they would be cannibals...

Comment: @ChanandlerBong maybe because they have food shortage?

Comment: @Luciano Are they? it is other specie.

Comment: @SSimon well... how far have you watched it? :)

Comment: @Luciano S2E3 :D

Answer (score 3):

A few reasons:

1. Pilcher doesn't want the people who live in Wayward pines to know about the Abbies. Obviously having unidentifiable Abbie meat might raise some flags.
2. They are difficult to kill and would essentially be game animals; meaning that all the difficulty they would go through to capture/kill a proper amount of Abbies to feed the town would be quite significant and for not a lot of payoff.
3. They didn't have a need; their stock supplies would have lasted them a few years - they would concentrate on actions that produced the most bang for the buck. So, farms, and livestock. Keeping a pen of Abbies would not be efficient.
4. They're humans - people have had an aversion to eating human meat for millennia. Granted Abbies are evolved humans, they are still humans. It'd be a difficult sell for Pilcher.